# Convert string to datetime in C#.net

Tags: c#, datetime

Can someone help me convert the string 14/04/2010 10:14:49.PM to datetime in C#.net without losing the time format?

Comment: What do you mean by *without losing the time format*?

Answer (score 5):

```
var date = DateTime.ParseExact(@"14/04/2010 10:14:49.PM", @"dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss.tt", null);
```

For string representation use

```
date.ToString(@"dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss.tt");
```

Also you can create extention method like this:

```
    public enum MyDateFormats
    {
        FirstFormat, 
        SecondFormat
    }

    public static string GetFormattedDate(this DateTime date, MyDateFormats format)
    {
       string result = String.Empty;
       switch(format)  
       {
          case MyDateFormats.FirstFormat:
             result = date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss.tt");
           break;
         case MyDateFormats.SecondFormat:
             result = date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
            break;
       }

       return result;
    }
```

Comment: The string representation should use hh instead of HH. During parsing the difference is not that big but for output you would get 23h instead of 11h (PM)

Comment: The extension method also needs to be static.

Comment: ohh, yes. It just because i haven't vs near me. Updated.

Answer (score 3):

```
DateTime result =DateTime.ParseExact(@"14/04/2010 10:14:49.PM", @"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.tt",null);
```

You can now see the PM or AM and null value for format provider

Answer (score 1):

```
DateTime.ParseExact(@"14/04/2010 10:14:49.PM", @"dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime.Parse(@"14/04/2010 10:14:49.PM");
```

that should work, not near VS at the moment so i cannot try it

Comment: this has an ambiguous date/month format, so that won't work in some scenarios

Comment: I agree with Myster. The behaviour is locale dependent.

Comment: Assuming this is the correct format of DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo , this should work.

Answer (score 0):

Use convert function

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace stackOverflow
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {

            Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToDateTime("14/04/2010 10:14:49.PM"));
            Console.Read();

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using `DateTime.ParseExact` as the `Parse` method behaves slightly differently according to the current thread locale settings.

```
DateTime.ParseExact(yourString,
    "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss.tt", null)
```