# How to convert 31/03/2011 00:00:00 date format to 31 Mar 2011 in C#

Tags: c#

I have got below date format in my result,I am using C# 2.0

```
ExpiryDate = "31/03/2011 00:00:00";
spnExpiryDate.InnerHtml = ExpiryDate;
```

Now when I am going to show this in HTML it should be converted to `31 Mar 2011` format.

Please suggest!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, parse the string to a `DateTime`, and then format it using the `DateTime`'s `ToString`:

```
DateTime myDateTime = DateTime.Parse( "31/03/2011 00:00:00" );
spnExpiryDate.InnerHtml = myDateTime.ToString("dd MMM yyyy");
```

Comment: One question, what culture info do you use because if I try this example I get that the string is not identifiable as a date and it would be nice to know how to get DateTime parse to accept this format.

Comment: Found a more complete answer in MarkXA's answer that does not require you to have the correct default culture set.

Answer (score 3):

This should do it:

```
var culture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-GB");
spnExpiryDate.InnerHtml = DateTime.Parse(ExpiryDate, culture).ToString("d MMM yyyy");
```

You can leave out the culture bits if your server's default culture is already dd/mm/yyyy.

Comment: This one was the only one that worked for me probably because I do not have en-GB as default culture.

Answer (score 2):

First parse date then format how you need:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse("31/03/2011 00:00:00");
 .InnerHtml =  String.Format("{0:dd MMM yyyy}", dt);
```

There is good [link](http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/) that i use almost everytime when i need format date.
Also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4360891/convert-string-to-datetime-in-c-net/4360923#4360923) aswer about extention method for datetime formatting.

Answer (score 1):

at first parse your string to DateTime

```
var date = DateTime.Parse("31/03/2011 00:00:00", "dd/mm/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
```

then user method "ToString"

```
date.ToString("dd MMM yyyy")
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say how you are outputting it, but basically you want to provide the format when you call the ToString:

```
aTextBox.Text = myDate.ToString("dd MMMM yyyy");
```

Answer (score 0):

The another way is

```
CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(DateTime.Now.Month);
```

gives you Month Name