# Convert String to DateTime in C# - String was not recognized as a valid DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime

I reviewed the question here: [Convert string to datetime in C#.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4360891/convert-string-to-datetime-in-c-net)

The format I'm trying to pass is only slightly different, but cannot get it to work.

My code:

```
var date = DateTime.ParseExact(@"28/06/2012 06:04:10 PM", @"dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", null);
```

So then I tried the example code from the question mentioned above:

```
var date = DateTime.ParseExact(@"14/04/2010 10:14:49.PM", @"dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss.tt", null);
```

That doesn't work either. Both give me

```
System.FormatException
String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: I assume this is some kind of localisation issue. What culture are you? Have you tried it with invariant culture stuff?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is localisation.

Consider these three statements:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(@"14/04/2010 10:14:49.PM", @"dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss.tt", new CultureInfo("fr-fr"))
DateTime.ParseExact(@"14/04/2010 10:14:49.PM", @"dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss.tt", new CultureInfo("en"))
DateTime.ParseExact(@"14/04/2010 10:14:49.PM", @"dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss.tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

The first will not work whereas the last two will. In this case it is because the `PM` is not valid in `fr-fr`. If you try this:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(@"14/04/2010 10:14:49.", @"dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss.tt", new CultureInfo("fr-fr"))
```

it will work fine.

As has been noted in comments other cultures may fail on other items. `en-za` uses a different date separator causing that to fail.

Comment: Thank you Chris! Seems to work if I use CultureInfo.InvariantCulture. Using CultureInfo.CurrentCulture breaks, which I don't understand. CurrentCulture is en-us. The 'PMDesignator' for en-us is set as 'PM', so why would this still fail? Same goes for en-za.

Comment: So if you do `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name` it tells you it is `en-us`? That doesn't seem right since the above statements if used with explicitly `en-us` works for me. In the case of en-za it looks like it is probably the date separator that is causing problems though. Changing the `/` for `-` (`culture.DateTimeFormat.DateSeparator`) makes it work. This is why specifying the culture is so necessary.

Answer (score 0):

```
var dateString = "28/06/2012 06:04:10 PM";
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, "M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 0):

`/` is date separator and probably in your culture it's not exactly `/`. The same issue can occur with `:`, which is replaced with current culture time separator. Try escaping both `/` and `:`:

```
var date = DateTime.ParseExact(@"28/06/2012 06:04:10 PM", @"dd\/MM\/yyyy hh\:mm\:ss tt", null);
```

Comment: Indeed, @Chris is correct. The PM designator doesn't seem to work on the current culture (en-us), whereas if I simply use InvariantCulture it works....