# Converting this string format to a valid DateTime?

Tags: c#, string, datetime, string-conversion

The string in question: `"2003:12:14 12:01:44"` (yyyy:MM:dd hh:mm:ss)

How would I be able to convert this to a valid datetime in C#? I tried `Convert.ToDateTime(str)`, but to no avail.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert string to datetime in C#.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4360891/convert-string-to-datetime-in-c-net)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the right `DateTime` format and supply `DateTime.ParseExact` with that format. Note that since your `time` doesn't show AM or PM, it may be safer to assume that it uses 24-Hr format (use capital `HH`) than 12-Hr AM PM (not `hh`) format. The following code should work:

```
string format = "yyyy:MM:dd HH:mm:ss"; //note: use HH not hh
var result = DateTime.ParseExact("2003:12:14 12:01:44", format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Check more on the available `DateTime` formats [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx) (standard) and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx) (custom).

Answer (score 1):

`Convert.ToDateTime` try to parse your string as a standard date and time format of your `CurrentCulture` settings. Looks like this string is not a standard format.

You can use [`DateTime.ParseExact`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parseexact) for specify custom format.

```
var dt = DateTime.ParseExact("2003:12:14 12:01:44", 
                             "yyyy:MM:dd hh:mm:ss", 
                             CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```